# creating huge optionlist with javascript vs delivering them in markup

Tags: javascript, html

I have a .net page that contains a huge amount of always the same dropdownlist in a repeater. The rendering performance of this site is...dispappointing.

I played around with delivering only the values and display texts for the dropdownlist to the page and then filling the selects with javascript. Works well, but I can't really see an improvement. In the end the page spends a lot of time with appending the options to the select tags.

Can someone with more experience tell me if it is theoretically possible to be faster than just filling the select tags in markup. Feels to me as if the browser has to "create" it at least once per select tag anyway, so it may not matter where the options come from. But maybe my javascript solution is just not very performat

Load time isnt't really a concern - it is for an intranet page.

Comment: what is `huge amount`? Have you tried loading page first without options, then do an Ajax call, get all options and add them. That way at least your page is loaded fast and can be worked with

Comment: can i post your code?

Comment: sorry, code is on the work computer - no access right now. Ajax might be worth a try  -most of the dropdowns are hidden by a pager anyway.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I did in the end:

I create an option list of 1 element for every select control to preserve the preselected values. If a select is focused or hovered over, I check if it contains onyl one element. If yes, I fill it dynamically from a collection of key values. It works without delay even for very large option lists.

I register an event listener for every select box and call this function

```
function fillDDL(ddl, arr) {
var i, len;
var optVals;

if (ddl.options.length === 1) {
    var val = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var opt;
    ddl.remove(0);

    opt = new Option("", "", true, false);
    docfrag.appendChild(opt);
    for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        optVals = arr[i];
        opt = new Option(optVals[1], optVals[0], false, optVals[0] === val);
        docfrag.appendChild(opt);
    }
    ddl.appendChild(docfrag);
}
```

Maybe innerHTML would be even faster, but right now I get instant results anyway.